# Custom Column or Row for Grid - delphi 10.1 berlin

Tags: delphi, grid, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am looking for a solution to create a custom column or row for a fmx.grid or fmx.stringgrid in Dlphi 10.1, like numberbox column.
there are some explanations using CreateCellControl funtion, but not working in 10.1

Answer (score 1):

It seems `CreateCellControl` doesn't exist anymore in Delphi 10.1 Berlin (it existed at least in XE7, which I checked, and probably in other versions too).

I suggest you use `TCurrencyColumn` which limits entries to numeric only and aligns entries to the right of the column. Alternatively you can check and prevent wrong entries in the `OnSetValue` event.

Comment: I can confirm that TStringColumn.CreateCellControl existed in Delphi 10 Seattle, but no longer exists in 10.1 Berlin.